# yii filter without press tab/enter

Tags: php, yii

I need to change yii gridview filter to auto search(not autocomplete). for example I have an item name :**StackOverflow**. for this I need to type **stack** then press tab/enter to get the results. if I enter **Sta** the items will display which items start with letters **sta**(without press tab/enter keys).help me.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi please use below widget

<input type="hidden" name="formula_formula" id="formula_formula" value="">
                        <?php 
                            $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete',
                                array(
                                    'name'=>'tff',
                                    'source'=>'js: function(request, response) {
                                        $.ajax({
                                            url: "'.$this->createUrl('youraction').'",
                                            dataType: "json",
                                            data: {
                                                term: request.term,
                                                name: "treatment_formula_formula",
                                                pk : "tff_id"
                                            },
                                            success: function (data) {
                                                response(data);
                                            }
                                        })
                                    }',
                                    'htmlOptions'=> array('placeholder'=>'Formula List', 'class' => 'form-control auto_comp_search'),
                                    'options' => array(
                                            'autoFocus' => true,
                                            'showAnim' => 'fold',
                                            'minLength' => '0',
                                            'select'=>'js:function( event, ui ) {
                                                $(ui).hide();
                                                $("#formula_formula").val(ui.item.id);
                                            }'
                                        ),
                            ));
                        ?>
```